# Display Different Text When Logged In in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, railscasts

I have been following the Railscast #270 found [Rails Cast #270](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1) about implementing Authentication in Rails 3.1. What I would like to do is have the ability in my templates to have different links displayed if a user is logged in. It should look something like this.

```
If user logged in
  Display link to Profile
  Display logout
If user logged out
 Display link to register
 Display link to login
```

I think I can figure out the link to various places from theRailsTutorial, but I'm stuck on how to tell if a user is signed in or not.

Using the rails tutorial I found this snippet

```
 <% if signed_in? %>
     <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %> sfsdfsdf</li>
 <% end %>
```

Which doesn't work when I put the following in my sessions helper:

```
    def signed_in?
      !@current_user.nil?  
end
```

How would you make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `current_user`.

so just

```
 <% if current_user %>
     <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %> sfsdfsdf</li>
 <% end %>
```

btw in HAML that would be just

```
 -if current_user
   %li= 
     link_to "Profile", current_user, sfsdfsdf
```

(the ends get implied - both for the HTML `<li>` tag (i.e. the `</li>`) AND for the ruby `if` statement!)
For anyone not using HAML this should wet your appetite :)

current_user itself uses @current_user and it gets set up in your application controller as in:

```
  helper_method :current_user

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
```

Comment: Is @current_user and current_user the same thing? If this were normal ruby they wouldn't be, but does Rails do something magically so @ current_user is defined in application controller and then you access it via current_user in the views? Is this a common rails pattern?

Comment: @NoahClark, `@current_user` and `current_user` are not the same thing. One in an instance variable and the other is a method. `@current_user` is set-up inside a method called `current_user` (which is in application_controller.rb). If you changed the name of the method to `def current_foo` then you would use that instead to check `@current_user`. We call the method `current_user` for convenience

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes perfect sense. Thanks. I still struggle with this idea of methods not having parens on the end. I'll get it figured out though!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like to need to set up the `current_user` method. Here's how ryan bates does it in railscast 270:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  # don't forget this line too 
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

Make sure you've got that in application_controller.rb. No need to use `if signed_in` anymore, although it should still work if you'd prefer to continue with it

Comment: ps - If you are going to define a `signed_in` method, then you should almost certainly think about moving it from your sessions_helper (where it is only available to sessions views) into application_controller.rb where you can make it globally available with the help of `helper_method :signed_in`

Comment: My application controller looks exactly like yours.